# How does bind automatically pass the event argument to an event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The React docs [page on Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) states:

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.deleteRow(id, e)}>Delete Row</button>
<button onClick={this.deleteRow.bind(this, id)}>Delete Row</button>
```

> In both cases, the e argument representing the React event will be
>   passed as a second argument after the ID. With an arrow function, we
>   have to pass it explicitly, but with bind any further arguments are
>   automatically forwarded.

So, when using `bind`, the event is is passed as an argument to the event handler in the callback--how/why does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get that answer if you check the `polyfill` for bind, I mean what exactly bind do.

Bind basically returns a new function, whenever you call that function (returned by bind), it will merge all the parameters (parameter passed during binding and parameter passed to function returned by bind), then pass that to original function.

Check this [polyfill (Source- MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill):

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) (function(){
  var ArrayPrototypeSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
  Function.prototype.bind = function() {
    var thatFunc = this, thatArg = arguments[0];

    // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ argument bound to function
    var args = ArrayPrototypeSlice.call(arguments, 1);


    if (typeof thatFunc !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - ' + 'what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }
    return function(){

      // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ check here, this line is basically merging all the arguments
      args.push.apply(args, arguments);


      // ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ here, it will call the function with particular context and all the parameters
      return thatFunc.apply(thatArg, args);
    };
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is interesting, but I'm still not sure how the event is passed. Maybe where you say it's called with that particular context, but to me it's not clear from that code how it's done.

Comment: see this line: `return thatFunc.apply(thatArg, args);` here thatArg will be the context, and args will be all the merged arguments. In this line `args.push.apply(args, arguments);` event will be available in `arguments`. In every function `arguments` variable (predefined) represent all the arguments passed to that function. check [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) for more details about the same.